# How do I flatten/pivot a sql result set?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL result set that looks like the following:

[image: Sql Result Set]

How can I get this result to display only ONE row for each ItemCode? Using a GROUP BY does not seem to work as it requires me to include columns that prevent the grouping I'm looking for.

The query I have written is pulling data from a table with a row for each warehouse and I am trying to format it in a way that I only have one row for each ItemCode. I think pivoting is the term what I'm trying to do..

Here is what my query looks like currently:

```
SELECT 
    ItemCode, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Quantity WHERE WhsCode = 10), 0) 'Whs10QTY', 
    ISNULL((SELECT Quantity WHERE WhsCode = 20), 0) 'Whs20QTY',
    ISNULL((SELECT SalesAmt WHERE WhsCode = 10), 0) 'Whs10SalesAmt',
    ISNULL((SELECT SalesAmt WHERE WhsCode = 20), 0) 'Whs20SalesAmt',
    ISNULL((SELECT GrssProfit WHERE WhsCode = 10), 0) 'Whs10GrssProfit',
    ISNULL((SELECT GrssProfit WHERE WhsCode = 20), 0) 'Whs20GrssProfit'
FROM 
    @Table t
```

Note: I may need help rewording and retitling this question as to make it more useful for the community. Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify this as such:

```
Select ItemCode
      ,Whs10QTY        = sum(case when WhsCode = 10 then Quantity else 0 end)
      ,Whs20QTY        = sum(case when WhsCode = 20 then Quantity else 0 end)
      ,Whs10SalesAmt   = sum(case when WhsCode = 10 then SalesAmt else 0 end)
      ,Whs20SalesAmt   = sum(case when WhsCode = 20 then SalesAmt else 0 end)
      ,Whs10GrssProfit = sum(case when WhsCode = 10 then GrssProfit else 0 end)
      ,Whs20GrssProfit = sum(case when WhsCode = 20 then GrssProfit else 0 end)
 From @Table t
 Group By ItemCode
```

Comment: @Dezryth Happy to help.